# Setting up perspective projection in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++, graphics-programming, perspective, projection-matrix

I'm trying to set up perspective projection in OpenGL but it doesn't work

```
void Camera::setViewportSize(float left, float right, float bottom, float top)
{
    constexpr float fov = glm::radians(45.0f);
    m_projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(fov, (right - left) / (top - bottom), 0.1f, 10.0f);
    recalculateViewMatrix();
}

void Camera::recalculateViewMatrix() 
{
    glm::mat4 translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(m_position, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 rotate = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), m_rotation, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    glm::mat4 scale = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(m_scale, m_scale, 1.0f));

    m_viewMatrix = translate * rotate * scale;
    m_viewMatrix = glm::inverse(m_viewMatrix);

    m_viewProjectionMatrix = m_projectionMatrix * m_viewMatrix;
}
```

I upload viewProjectionMatrix to shader and use it like this:

```
gl_Position = u_viewProjectionMatrix * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
```

It just doesn't show anything.
I double checked if I pass good left, right, bottom, top values and it should be all good.
Playing with zNear and zFar didn't change anything.
Note - When I use ortho, it works like a charm:

```
    m_projectionMatrix = glm::ortho(left, right, bottom, top, 1.0f, -1.0f);
```

[image]

**Update**
I did add model matrix and I translated it -2 units on z axis. I can see the lines:
[image]
But they are disorted.

They should be at positions:

```
line1: (0.0f, 0.0f), (100.0, 100.0)
line2: (0.0f, 0.0f), (600.0f, 800.0f)
```

It seem like the centre of screen is at (0, 0)???

Comment: Keep in mind that you can use the Edit link at the bottom to modify an existing question instead of deleting and posting a new one. Then you can flag any comments that are no longer needed for us moderators to delete.

Comment: @DMGregory OK, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Check camera settings, viewport dimensions, OpenGL errors, object positions, and shader code for perspective projection in OpenGL.

Comment: If it works for otho, then why it doesn't work for perspective?
I mean should I change shader code or my object positions?